# Cannot concatenate int to list when using range()

Tags: python

In the below code I am trying to read data from the table.Used for loop and range function.But I am facing type error.
**Data I am reading:**

```
BookName    Author  Subject Price
Learn Selenium  Amit    Selenium    300
Learn Java  Mukesh  Java    500
Learn JS    Animesh Javascript  300
Master In Selenium  Mukesh  Selenium    3000
Master In Java  Amod    JAVA    2000
Master In JS    Amit    Javascript  1000
```

**Below is the code I am defining**

```
for r in range(2, str(rows + 1)):
    for c in range(1, str(columns + 1)):
        t1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//table[@name='BookTable']/tbody/tr[" + str(r) + "]/td[" +str(c)+ "]").text
        print(t1)
```

**I am encountering below error:**

```
for r in range(2, str(rows + 1)):
                          ~~~~~^~~
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list
```

Comment: `range` needs to take `int` values. But you gave it and int and a string. you should use `int(row + 1)` instead of `str(row + 1)`

Comment: @ArtemStrogin According to the error, `rows` is a list, so that would throw same error

Comment: Likely `str(rows + 1)` should instead be `len(rows) + 1`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate a list (`rows`), then you can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) rather than `range`

```
for row_index, row in enumerate(rows):
```

Otherwise, you need to use `range(len(rows))`, and you don't need to add +1 unless you want to get an IndexError, or there is some hidden row at the end of the HTML...

If you want to skip the first row only, then extract the generator and call `next()`

```
row_iter = enumerate(rows)
next(row_iter)
for row_index, row in row_iter:
  # similar for columns
```

Alternatively, [`pandas.read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#io-read-html) might be better for processing tables than XPath

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is because of using a str in the range instead of

`for r in range(2, str(rows + 1)):`

since rows is a list use:

`for r in range(2, len(rows) +1):`